Power Apps - SharePoint List, having 2 columns, retrieve all distinct values from one column relating to the other column
I have 2 SharePoint Lists, OBDATA and OB_StatusLog. OBDATA has OB_ID as a primary key. OB_StatusLog contains a log of timestamp Statuses and each OB_StatusLog record is related to OBDATA by the foreign key OBSL_OB_ID.
Each OBDATA record can have 1-to-many OB_StatusLog records. Meaning that each OBDATA record can have many Statuses.
A sample of the OB_StatusLog List is below:

What I am looking for is to display all the DISTINCT Statuses of each OBDATA.OB_ID record in a specific column in the gallery. Something like the below image:

I have tried to contain in a Collection, GroupBy and Distinct functions, but unfortunately unsuccessful so far. I would appreciate any help.
Thank you

After a number of tries I finally figured out the correct code.
First, we group the records by the foreign key OBSL_OB_ID:
ClearCollect(
    GroupedOBStatusLog,
    GroupBy(
        OB_StatusLog,
        OBSL_OB_ID,
        GroupedItems
    )
)

Then, we use the above grouped items. The GroupedItems contains a table of all the OBSL_Status values for each OBSL_OB_ID, therefore, we just need to add the Distinct function and retrieve the unique values in the Value:
ClearCollect(
    Collection_OBSL_StatusGroup,
    AddColumns(
        GroupedOBStatusLog,
        StatusList,
        Concat(
            Distinct(GroupedItems,OBSL_Status),
            Value,
            " "
        )
    )
)

I hope this helps anyone who had a similar problem with mine.
